# Finding out template

Tags: theming

I'm working on this web site which I need to make changes to the heading part and I need to know which template or file is generating it so that I can add a slogan. My first attempt was using theme developer. However, it crashed the site so I had to disable it. Is there any other way I can track down the responsible template?

Drupal 7.0

Comment: check on "page--front.tpl"(if present) for home page and page.tpl for all other pages.

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for [Theme developer](https://www.drupal.org/project/devel_themer) module:

> Firebug for Drupal themeing. See the [screenshot and screencast](http://drupal.org/node/209561). Note that this module injects markers into the DOM to do its magic. This may cause some themes to behave erratically and less capable browsers may make it worse (especially IE)/. Enable it when needed, and disable it afterwards.

[image]

---

## If it is crashing your website

You need to upgrade. You are at 7.0, current version is 7.31. You are **31** minor **versions behind**. And some of them was **security updates**. So you probably should upgrade anyway.

Comment: @KrishnaMohan Good point, either I failed to spot it, or OP edited his question during 5 minutes grace period (I started answering when question was about 2 minutes old). Anyway, answer updated.

Comment: Yeah, I think that happened during the 5 mins grace period, I just wanted to notify you. That why I deleted my comment after you update your answer. :)

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have authority to update drupal core.

Comment: @user30646 so you can try to download whole page and [`grep`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grep) over it to find out where original texts came from. Anyway, tell your employer that now his site is pretty much free to take over by anyone over the Internet who will realize it's 7.0 and without security updates.